# How to merge two matrices with pointers and dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c

I wrote this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define MAX(x,y) ((x > y) ? x : y)

int  MergeArray2D( int **retArrayPtr, int *retRowsPtr, int *retColsPtr,
                   int *leftArray, int leftRows, int leftCols,
                   int *rightArray, int rightRows, int rightCols )
{
    int  *retArray;
    int  i;
    int  j;
    int  retCols;
    int  retRows;

    if ((retArrayPtr == NULL) || (retColsPtr == NULL) || (retRowsPtr == NULL) || (leftArray == NULL))
        return (-1);

    retCols = leftCols + rightCols;
    retRows = MAX(leftRows, rightRows);

    retArray = calloc(sizeof(int), retRows * retCols);
    if (retArray == NULL)
        return (-2);

    /* First copy the left array into the merged array */
    for (i = 0; i < leftRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < leftCols; j++) {
            retArray[i * retCols + j] = leftArray[i * leftCols + j];
        }
    }

    /* And then copy the right array into the merged array */
    for (i = 0; i < rightRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < rightCols; j++) {
            retArray[i*retCols + j + leftCols] = rightArray[i * rightCols + j];
        }
    }

    *retArrayPtr = retArray;
    *retColsPtr = retCols;
    *retRowsPtr = retRows;

    return (0);
}

void  PrintArray2D( int **array, int numRows, int numCols )
{
    int  i;
    int  j;

    for (i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            printf(" %d", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int  main()
{
    int     leftRows;
    int     leftCols;
    int     **leftArray;
    int     rightRows;
    int     rightCols;
    int     **rightArray;
    int     i;
    int     j;
    int     count;
    int     result;
    int     *newArray;
    int     newRows;
    int     newCols;
    printf("sizeof(void *) = %d\n", sizeof(void *));
    printf("sizeof(int) = %d\n\n", sizeof(int));
    count = 0;

    printf("Matrix 1 -> ");
    scanf("%d%d", &leftRows, &leftCols);
    leftArray = calloc(sizeof(int **), leftRows);
    for (i = 0; i < leftRows; i++)
        *(leftArray+i) = calloc(sizeof(int *), leftCols);

    /* Initialize the left array */
    for (i = 0; i < leftRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < leftCols; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &leftArray[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Matrix 2 -> ");
    scanf("%d%d", &rightRows, &rightCols);
    rightArray = calloc(sizeof(int **), rightRows);
    for (i = 0; i < rightRows; i++)
        *(rightArray+i) = calloc(sizeof(int *), rightCols);

    /* Initialize the right array */
    for (i = 0; i < rightRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < rightCols; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &rightArray[i][j]);
        }
    }

    /* Print out the left array */
    printf("Left Array:\n");
    PrintArray2D( leftArray, leftRows, leftCols);

    /* Print out the right array */
    printf("\nRight Array:\n");
    PrintArray2D( rightArray, rightRows, rightCols);

    /* Merge the two arrays */
    result = MergeArray2D(&newArray, &newRows, &newCols, *leftArray, leftRows, leftCols, *rightArray, rightRows, rightCols);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("ERROR -- MergeArrays2D() returned %d\n", result);
    }

    /* Print out the merged array */
    printf("\nMerged Array:\n");
    PrintArray2D(&newArray, newRows, newCols);

    /* Clean up the allocated merged array when through using it */
    free(newArray);
}
```

However, it only prints the first row after merging both the matrices and none of the rows 1st index onwards. I think it has to do something with my calloc function and parameters passed while calling MergeArray2D. I have tried many changes since the past 3 days but nothing seems to work. Can you suugest me the required changes in the code please?

Here's the output from CLion :

```
sizeof(void *) = 4
sizeof(int) = 4

Matrix 1 ->2 2
1 2 3 4
 Matrix 2 ->2 2
4 5 6 7
 Left Array:
 1 2
 3 4

Right Array:
 4 5
 6 7

Merged Array:
 1 2 4 5

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different matrix representations.

The left and right array are two dimensional:

```c
    leftArray = calloc(sizeof(int **), leftRows);
    for (i = 0; i < leftRows; i++)
        *(leftArray+i) = calloc(sizeof(int *), leftCols);
```

The merged array is one dimensional

```
    retArray = calloc(sizeof(int), retRows * retCols);
```

The same print function cannot print both representations.

You should choose one matrix representation and stick to it.

---

Further to your comment, if you change `MergeArray2D` to something like this and fix up the types in `main` you should be good.

```c
int  MergeArray2D( int ***retArrayPtr, int *retRowsPtr, int *retColsPtr,
                   int **leftArray, int leftRows, int leftCols,
                   int **rightArray, int rightRows, int rightCols )
{
    int  **retArray;
    int  i;
    int  j;
    int  retCols;
    int  retRows;

    if ((retArrayPtr == NULL) || (retColsPtr == NULL) || (retRowsPtr == NULL) || (leftArray == NULL))
        return (-1);

    retCols = leftCols + rightCols;
    retRows = MAX(leftRows, rightRows);
    
    retArray = calloc(sizeof(int **), retRows);
    for (i = 0; i < retRows; i++)
        *(retArray+i) = calloc(sizeof(int *), retCols);
    /* TODO: Add error checking here */

    /* First copy the left array into the merged array */
    for (i = 0; i < leftRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < leftCols; j++) {
            retArray[i][j] = leftArray[i][j];
        }
    }

    /* And then copy the right array into the merged array */
    for (i = 0; i < rightRows; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < rightCols; j++) {
            retArray[i][j+leftCols] = rightArray[i][j];
        }
    }

    *retArrayPtr = retArray;
    *retColsPtr = retCols;
    *retRowsPtr = retRows;

    return (0);
}
```

I would note, you would have now repeated that matrix allocation code three times in your program. You should probably consider factoring that out into a function. You'll probably also need a matrix deallocation function too. While you are doing this, you might think about whether you should create a matrix struct to keep all the information about a matrix together.

Comment: int  **retArray = calloc(sizeof(int **), retRows * retCols);
    for (i = 0; i < retRows; i++)
        *(retArray+i) = calloc(sizeof(int *), retCols);
If I do this instead, am still getting errors.